# Regular Expression to find text between tags that are not commented out

Tags: .net, regex, expression

I have a simple scenario that seems to be stumping me. I want to get the text between two tags which are not commented out. Here is an example:

```
// Example of commented text
// :Start
// <I don't want to get this text>
// :End


:Start
<Here is the text i want>
:End
```

**Solution:**

Thanks to all for your help. Received the answer super fast and does exactly what I need. I went with the following regular expression because it worked best for my situation. Special thanks to Tim Pietzcker:

```
(?sm)(?<=^:Start\s*)(?:(?!^:End).)*
```

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? This is relevant information because the obvious solution requires a feature that not all regex engines have.

Comment: Also, are these the only two possible situations, or could there be (between two tags) some lines that are commented out, and some that are not, for example?

Comment: I'm using the regex engine that comes with .Net.

Comment: UPDATE: I will need the ability to NOT match on any lines that might be commented out in between the :Start and :End tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?sm)(?<=^:Start\s*)(?:(?!^:End).)*
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?sm)     # Set options: . matches newline, ^ matches start-of line
(?<=      # Assert that this regex can be matched before the current position:
 ^        #  Start of line
 :Start   #  :Start
 \s*      #  Any whitespace
)         # End of lookahead
(?:       # Try to match...
 (?!      # (unless the following regex could be matched here:)
   ^      #  Start of line
   :End   #  :End
 )        #  End of lookahead
 .        # ... any character
)*        # Repeat any number of times
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you! This solution is so easy to understand and is exactly what I was looking for. Works great.

Comment: Just because I'm a "wise ass": your regex will also match:`:Start \EOL
//<Here is the text i want> \EOL
:End \EOL`  where `\EOL` stands for End-Of-Line. Still +1 for a very nice solution!

Comment: Are you suggesting the need for a modification 'alfasin'?

Comment: @alfasin: That's why had I asked if lines like these need to be taken into account, and the OP said no.

Comment: Tim, after further review, I to have commented text BETWEEN the tags (what alfasin was pointing out above). I would want to ignore any lines that are commented in my match. Could you kindly update your regular expression to not match on lines within the tags that are commented out? My apologies for the change.

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde: This cannot be done in a single regex, at least not if you want each start/end segment as one entire match. It would be much easier to do this in two steps: First match between an uncommented start/end tag, then take the result and remove any commented lines.

Comment: Ok! Sounds good. I can do that no problem. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this, seems to be robust enough. Also catches multiple lines:

```
(?s)(?<=(?<!/+\s*):Start\s+)(?!//).+\s(?=:End)
```

(?s) at the begging for SingleLine option.

Comment: This solution also worked for me, however it returns matches for empty lines and lines with text. It might just be the way my automation tool is using the regular expression. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should do it. Basically the tags must be at the start of the line, that distinguishes real tags from commented tags.

```
"\n:Start\n([^\n\/]+)\n:End"
```

Here's an example in Python. `s` is your example text.

```
r = re.search("\n:Start\n([^\n\/]+)\n:End", s)
r.group(1)
'<Here is the text i want>'
```

I'm not completely sure about the syntax in .NET, but looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) I suppose it should look something like:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, "\n:Start\n([^\n\/]+)\n:End"))
    Console.WriteLine("'{1}'), match.Groups[1].Value)
```

Comment: Great idea. I tried your solution but was unable to get it to work. Give me a second to play around with it a little and I'll see if i can get it to work. Unfortunately i am using an automation tool that somewhat limits my ability to use regular expressions. The backside of the tool is .Net though so something like what you have above should work i think...

Comment: Thank you for your help and example. I was unable to use your regular expression only because the automation tool im working with does allow programmatic implementations.